# Akka-Spray object marshall

Tags: json, scala, akka, marshalling, spray

I am experimenting with aka and spray, what I want to achieve is a simple object marshalling service.

When I try to compile the code I get the following error :

> ```
> Error:(33, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller:
>   spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[ExampleApplication.Password]
>   marshal(Password(randomString(8),i,0))
>                    ^
> ```

Here is the code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.http.HttpEntity
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.json._

object ExampleApplication extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit var i = 0;


  object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val PasswordFormat = jsonFormat3(Password)
  }

  case class Password(pass: String, count: Int, complexity: Int)

  def newPass(cplx: Int):Password = {return Password(randomString(cplx),i,0)}

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    get {
      path("passgen") {
        i+=1
        complete {
          marshal(newPass(8))
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def randomString(n: Int): String = {
    n match {
      case 1 => util.Random.nextPrintableChar().toString
      case _ => util.Random.nextPrintableChar.toString ++ randomString(n - 1).toString
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still failing to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes to fix it:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
```

Then even though you define the JsonProtocol object right in your app you must still import it's members explicitly:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val PasswordFormat = jsonFormat3(Password)
}
import MyJsonProtocol._
```

That looks a little repetitive in this case, but in most use cases you'll have it defined somewhere else.

*Optional*

You can complete the call without explicitly calling `marshal`:

```
complete {
  newPass(8)
}
```

Comment: That did it, yesterday was quite late, and at late hours you write silly code, still for the httpx import I am puzzled that it won't be auto imported